# Correct verb to be use with bow and arrow

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, verbs

What is the more accurate verb that should be used with shooting an arrow? 
Should it be “shoot” or “launch”?
e.g.,

- I shot an arrow.
- I launched an arrow.

I used to think “shot” is the correct word for a long time, but recently I heard someone using “launch”. 
English is not my first language, so it got me wondering.

Comment: *Shoot* is still correct. Sometimes you will want to use another verb for the sake of variety: *loose*, *release*, etc. *Launch* is a bit unconventional, but certainly possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to **shoot** would be my choice  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/178501?rskey=VAJrN1&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> to fly as an arrow from a bow

As in:

> 2006   Roanoke (Virginia) Times (Nexis) 3 Mar. b2   Begin with the
>   season's most prominent constellation, Orion. Simply **shoot an arrow**
>   through its three belt stars to the northwest. It hits reddish
>   Aldebaran. Bull's-eye!

Comment: @VaibhavVishal link points to quoted sentence in OED

Comment: removed that link ... added link: 'to shoot'

Comment: thanks for the help bro, but the link still isn't working. It wants me to log in, but there is no option to register. But don't worry about that.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal You can refer to the Oxford Dictionaries [definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shoot), which is not behind a paywall.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shoot%20an%20arrow%2C%20launch%20an%20arrow&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshoot%20an%20arrow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claunch%20an%20arrow%3B%2Cc0) shows that the more common usage is to “shoot an arrow”.

[Launch an arrow](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22launch%20an%20arrow%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) is used, though:

From [Bowhunter's Guide to Accurate Shooting](https://books.google.it/books?id=Bkgw5TWTpBUC&pg=PA100&dq=%22launch%20an%20arrow%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix0viU9q7eAhWpLMAKHWg5AkcQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22launch%20an%20arrow%22&f=false):

> Many factors affect a bow's ability to launch an arrow at a higher velocity, which in turn flattens arrow trajectory.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/launch), to launch:

> to throw forward, hurl:
>
> - launched an arrow at a target

Answer (score -1):

You **loose** or **throw** an arrow from a bow after the draw and release.

You *chuck* an arrow from your hand.

You *shoot* a shot from a gun.

You *launch* a rock from a catapult.

Using these terminologies greatly reduces confusion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Only the first line addresses the question, and I really don't think it's idiomatic.

Comment: We are trying to use correct terminology, and not finding an idiomatic word

Comment: I think 'loose' is an excellent alternative to 'shoot' and 'launch'. 'Throw' is sometimes used in the relevant context (e.g., "He knew ... that a bigger bow threw an arrow farther" in Robin McKinley, [_The Outlaws of Sherwood_](https://books.google.com/books?id=AFqLDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&dq=%22threw+an+arrow%22+bow&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiruJ7Ol-qCAxXPIkQIHc5IBU44ChDoAXoECA4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22threw%20an%20arrow%22%20bow&f=false) [2005]), but 'throw an arrow' is more often used in the sense of 'throw by hand' than of 'release from a bow'. In fact, 'release' might work better.